# package drc LL.3

Tags: r, function, drc

I would like to access the code of the three-parameter log-logistic function in the drc package

I know that there is a whole repository on GitHub drc but I can't figure out which script in it describes action of function LL.3.

I apologize if my question seems trivial but I'm really new to it and that's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: Does `body(LL.3)` (or `body(drc::LL.3)`) give you what you want?

Comment: no  it only gives  a snippet of code not whole function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I view the source code for a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function)